# Woocommerce - Provide Associated Category Link for Product List Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a widget/plugin that lists a selectable number of products for a selected product_cat. I'm struggling with passing the associated URL for a chosen product_cat to the product_cat title residing above the list of products for any given product_cat. I am able to select a product_cat and render a number of associated products, but I'm failing to provide a title that is wrapped in a link to the correct product_cat. Here's my code. I really appreciate any help. I'm struggling with get_cat_ID and get_category_link. I'm doing something wrong. I've serched and tried foreach solutions, but I'm not getting it.

```
// Register widget

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'redding420_register_widget_cat_recent_posts' );

function redding420_register_widget_cat_recent_posts() {

register_widget( 'redding420_widget_cat_recent_posts' );

}

class redding420_widget_cat_recent_posts extends WP_Widget {

public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct(

        'redding420_widget_cat_recent_posts',
        __( 'Recent Posts by Category', 'recent-posts-by-category-widget' ),
        array(
            'classname'   => 'redding420_widget_cat_recent_posts widget_recent_entries',
            'description' => __( 'Display recent blog posts from a specific category', 'recent-posts-by-category-widget' )
        )

    );

}

// Build the widget settings form

function form( $instance ) {

    $defaults  = array( 'title' => '', 'category' => '', 'number' => 5, 'show_date' => '' );
    $instance  = wp_parse_args( ( array ) $instance, $defaults );
    $title     = $instance['title'];
    $category  = $instance['category'];
    $number    = $instance['number'];
    $show_date = $instance['show_date'];

    ?>

    <p>
        <label for="redding420_widget_cat_recent_posts_title"><?php _e( 'Title' ); ?>:</label>
        <input type="text" class="widefat" id="redding420_widget_cat_recent_posts_title" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="redding420_widget_cat_recent_posts_category"><?php _e( 'Product Category' ); ?>:</label>

        <?php

        wp_dropdown_categories( array(
            'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
            'orderby'    => 'title',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'name'       => $this->get_field_name( 'category' ),
            'id'         => 'redding420_widget_cat_recent_posts_category',
            'class'      => 'widefat',
            'value_field'=> 'slug',
            'selected'   => $category

        ) );

        ?>

    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="redding420_widget_cat_recent_posts_number"><?php _e( 'Number of posts to show' ); ?>: </label>
        <input type="text" id="redding420_widget_cat_recent_posts_number" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'number' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $number ); ?>" size="3" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="redding420_widget_cat_recent_posts_show_date" class="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'show_date' ); ?>" <?php checked( $show_date, 1 ); ?> />
        <label for="redding420_widget_cat_recent_posts_show_date"><?php _e( 'Display post date?' ); ?></label>
    </p>

    <?php

}

// Save widget settings

function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {

    $instance              = $old_instance;
    $instance['title']     = wp_strip_all_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
    $instance['category']  = wp_strip_all_tags( $new_instance['category'] );
    $instance['number']    = is_numeric( $new_instance['number'] ) ? intval( $new_instance['number'] ) : 5;
    $instance['show_date'] = isset( $new_instance['show_date'] ) ? 1 : 0;

    return $instance;

}

// Display widget

function widget( $args, $instance ) {

    extract( $args );

    echo $before_widget;

    $title     = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );
    $category  = $instance['category'];
    $number    = $instance['number'];
    $show_date = ( $instance['show_date'] === 1 ) ? true : false;

    // *** THIS IS THE CODE I'M STRUGGLING WITH ***
    // Get the ID of a given category
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( $title );

   // Get the URL of this category
   $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );


    if ( !empty( $title ) ) echo $before_title . '<a href="' . $category_link . '">' . $title . '</a>' . $after_title;

    $cat_recent_posts = new WP_Query( array( 

        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => $number,
        'product_cat'    => $category

    ) );

    if ( $cat_recent_posts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $cat_recent_posts->have_posts() ) {
                $cat_recent_posts->the_post();

            echo 
            '<div class="card clickme cont-shadow">',
                        '<div class="card-block">',
                            '<div class="row">';

            echo '<div class="col-sm-2">',
                         '<a href="#myModal-' . get_the_ID() . '"' . 'data-toggle="modal"' . 'data-target="#myModal-' . get_the_ID() . '">';
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            echo the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'img-fluid') );
                            }
            echo   '</a>',
                     '</div>';

            echo '<div class="col-sm-10">',
                        '<a href="#myModal-' . get_the_ID() . '"' . 'data-toggle="modal"' . 'data-target="#myModal-' . get_the_ID() . '"' . 'class="link-color"' . '>' . '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>' . '</a>';
            echo    '<span>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</span>';
                            if ( $show_date ) echo '<span class="post-date">' . get_the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ) . '</span>';
            echo    '</div>';

            // Modal
            echo '<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-' . get_the_ID() . '"' . 'tabindex="-1"' . 'role="dialog"' . 'aria-labelledby="myModal-' . get_the_ID() . 'Title' . '"' . 'aria-hidden="true">',
                     '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">',
                         '<div class="modal-content">',
                             '<div class="modal-header">',
                             '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '"' . '>',
                             '<h2 class="modal-title" id="myModal-' . get_the_ID() . 'Title"' . '>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>',
                             '</a>',
                         '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">',
                             '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>',
                         '</button>',
                     '</div>';

            echo '<div class="modal-body">',
                            the_content(),
                     '</div>';

            echo '<div class="modal-footer">',
                         '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>',
                     '</div>',
                     '</div>',
                     '</div>',
                     '</div>',
                     '</div>',
                     '</div>',  
                     '</div>';
        }   

    } else {

        _e( '<h2>' . 'Nothing yet.' . '</h2>', 'recent-posts-by-category-widget' );

    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    echo '<a href="' . $category_link . '"' . 'title="Category Name"' . 'class="cat-fpmore"' . '>' . 'Read More From This Category:&nbsp;' . $title . '</a>',
    '<hr>';

    echo $after_widget;

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress StackExchange! Unfortunately, questions exclusively regarding 3rd party plugins is [considered to be off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and better asked using their respective support methods. Please [take the tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

`get_category_link` only works on built-in WP Categories. It does not work on WooCommerce Product Categories.

Use `get_term_link` instead.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $category_id,'product_cat') ?>">
    <?php echo $title; ?>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution returns this error:  `code` Empty Term
Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /Users/chrisparsons/Dropbox/SteelBridge/local-sites/redding420(v2).test/redding420_v2/wp-content/plugins/redding420-posts-by-category/redding420-posts-by-category.php on line 132 `code` I have tried rewriting it a few different ways, but the term is empty with get_term_link... and.. get_category_link returns content sans the link for the title. ...

Comment: https://forums.envato.com/t/can-anyone-help-me-with-wordpresss-get-term-link/75895/3

Comment: Yep! Thanks. Removing get_cat_ID() and replacing get_category_link() w/ $category_link = get_term_link($title, 'product_cat'); delivered the results needed. Thank you! The envato link above was key..